# How to Add a Function to an Already Deployed Smart Contract?

Tags: remix, binance

i create a contract on the BSC and i was testing it,

this is my contract

https://bscscan.com/address/0x8dee0418b841b6e18c27046a1097f590b0dd3dd8#code

and now i have around 2BNB stuck in the contract and i cant find a function on it to recover them or to send them to my address, is there any way to do that?

Comment: Nop, cant do that. And i'd suggest learning what you're doing before deploying to mainnet tbh

Comment: i know i cant edit it or add any function, but is there any way that i can claim the BNB that stuck in the contract it self ??

Comment: as you said, you don't have a function in your contract that allows you to do that. so no